# issue with axios unhandled promise internet explorer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, promise, axios

I am using `React` with `axios` and experiencing difficulties with IE11+ and seeing the following error:

> Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Unable to get property
>   'getHostNode' of undefined or null reference.

Everything works fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

```
export const getData = () => {
    return axios.get('data.json');
};
```

I then use this above call in a redux action

```
export const getAllData = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        api.getData().then(resp => {
            dispatch(getDataSuccess(resp.data));
            resolve(resp);
        }).catch(err => {
            dispatch(getDataError(err));
            reject(err);
        });
    };
};
```

Finally I call this action in my react component

```
......

componentWillMount() {
   this.props.getAllData();
}

.....
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you wrap your `api.getData()` in a promise?

Comment: @dcodesmith removed that `promise`. You're right it wasn't neccessary

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: @dcodesmith nope, same issue

Comment: And it works in other browsers?

Comment: @dcodesmith yep, perfectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153347/discussion-between-dcodesmith-and-raul-rodriguez).

Comment: What does `console.log(err.stack)` etc give?

Comment: @Bergi `err` is showing `ERROR! TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference
   "ERROR!"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference",
      message: "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference",
      name: "TypeError",
      number: -2146823281,
      stack: "TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference
   }
`

Comment: @Bergi could be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058203/unable-to-get-property-0-of-undefined-or-null-reference

Comment: Is that the complete stack? Line numbers and file names would be more interesting than the message repeated over and over

Comment: @Bergi see complete stack in the discussion https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153347/discussion-between-dcodesmith-and-raul-rodriguez

Comment: Ah. Might as well be a React bug, you should make a minimal reproducible test case and report it in their issue tracker.

Comment: @Bergi ok, so you don't think it is a axios/promise thing?

Comment: At least the stack trace suggests that, yes.